# Using SparkR, how to split a string column into 'n' multiple columns?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I’m working with SparkR 1.6 and I have a dataFrame of millions rows. One of the df's column, named « categories », contains strings that have the following pattern :

```
      categories
1 cat1,cat2,cat3
2      cat1,cat2
3     cat3, cat4
4           cat5
```

I would like to split each string and create « n » new columns, where « n » is the number of possible categories (here n = 5, but in reality it could be more than 50).
Each new column will contains a boolean for the presence/absence of the category, such as :

```
   cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  cat5
1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

How can this be performed using the sparkR api only ?

Thanks for your time.
Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with imports and dummy data:

```
library(magrittr)

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, data.frame(
  categories=c("cat1,cat2,cat3", "cat1,cat2", "cat3,cat4", "cat5")
))
```

Separate strings:

```
separated <- selectExpr(df, "split(categories, ',') AS categories")
```

get distinct categories:

```
categories <- select(separated, explode(separated$categories)) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  collect() %>%
  extract2(1)
```

build expressions list:

```
exprs <- lapply(
  categories, function(x) 
  alias(array_contains(separated$categories, x), x)
)
```

select and check results

```
select(separated, exprs) %>% head()
##    cat1  cat2  cat3  cat4  cat5
## 1  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 2  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
## 4 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @zero323, but it's an overkill!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Spark solution without using `SparkR::collect()`. If the column of the given Spark dataframe has the certain number of separators, here is my solution with the following assumptions:

```
# separator = '::'
# number of separators = 3
# name of the respective column = col
```

First you have to create the schema of the output dataframe with the split columns:

```
AddFieldsToSchema = function(existingSchema, newFieldNames, newFieldTypes) {
  # This somewhat tortured syntax is necessary because the existingSchema
  # variable is actually a Java object under the hood
  existingNames = unlist(lapply(existingSchema$fields(), function(field) {
    field$name()
  }))
  existingTypes = unlist(lapply(existingSchema$fields(), function(field) {
    field$dataType.simpleString()
  }))
  
  combinedNames = c(existingNames, newFieldNames)
  combinedTypes = c(existingTypes, newFieldTypes)
  
  return(CreateSchema(combinedNames, combinedTypes))
}
num_separator = 3 
sdf_schema = SparkR::schema(sdf) %>%
              AddFieldsToSchema(paste0('col_', seq(1, num_separator)),
                                c(rep('string', num_separator)))
```

Then you have a splitting function for the given column that will be used in **SparkR::dapply**:

```
my_func = function(x) {cbind(x, stringr::str_split_fixed(x$col, '::', 3))}

sdf_split = sdf %>% 
              SparkR::dapply(my_func, df_schema)
```