# How to explode columns?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

After:

```
val df = Seq((1, Vector(2, 3, 4)), (1, Vector(2, 3, 4))).toDF("Col1", "Col2")
```

I have this DataFrame in Apache Spark:

```
+------+---------+
| Col1 | Col2    |
+------+---------+
|  1   |[2, 3, 4]|
|  1   |[2, 3, 4]|
+------+---------+
```

How do I convert this into:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |
|  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A solution that doesn't convert to and from RDD:

```scala
df.select($"Col1", $"Col2"(0) as "Col2", $"Col2"(1) as "Col3", $"Col2"(2) as "Col3")
```

Or arguable nicer:

```scala
val nElements = 3
df.select(($"Col1" +: Range(0, nElements).map(idx => $"Col2"(idx) as "Col" + (idx + 2)):_*))
```

The size of a Spark array column is not fixed, you could for instance have:

```
+----+------------+
|Col1|        Col2|
+----+------------+
|   1|   [2, 3, 4]|
|   1|[2, 3, 4, 5]|
+----+------------+
```

So there is no way to get *the* amount of columns and create those. If you know the size is always the same, you can set `nElements` like this:

```scala
val nElements = df.select("Col2").first.getList(0).size
```

Comment: Nice answer. is there way to use advance DataSet APIs to achieve above in more type safe way? For e.g. how can I get rid of $"Col1"?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I guess not getting rid of it by just not adding it to the `select` :) I guess you don't want to name it explicitly? But I'm not sure how you see type safety coming into play necessarily. It is probably worth it to create a new question with a minimal example of what you want to do.

Comment: sure i'll add another question. but what i mean is DataSet of spark provides good compile time safety. Where as $"col1" would be evaluated at run time. So if col1 is not present in dataset I get compile time error in select statement rather than getting at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Just to give the Pyspark version of [sgvd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37392793/6028910). If the array column is in `Col2`, then this select statement will move the first `nElements` of each array in `Col2` to their own columns:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F            
df.select([F.col('Col2').getItem(i) for i in range(nElements)])
```

Comment: how would you add "Col1" to the select statement?

Comment: @user422930, thank-you for your question, sorry I only saw it now. Try doing something like:

`from pyspark.sql import functions as F            
df.select([F.col('Col1')]+[F.col('Col2').getItem(i) for i in range(nElements)])`

I haven't tested it, but let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just add on to **sgvd's** solution:

If the size is not always the same, you can set nElements like this:

```scala
val nElements = df.select(size('Col2).as("Col2_count"))
                  .select(max("Col2_count"))
                  .first.getInt(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map:

```
df.map {
    case Row(col1: Int, col2: mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => (col1, col2(0), col2(1), col2(2))
}.toDF("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4").show()
```

Comment: What if I don't know how many colums I have on the array ? I would Like to have something like explodeToColums

Comment: @JorgeMachado, you can find my solution for explodeToColumns in SparkR  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919194/using-sparkr-how-to-split-a-string-column-into-n-multiple-columns/73677719#73677719

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with `SparkR`, you can find [**my answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73677719/1874449) where you don't need to use `explode` but you need `SparkR::dapply` and `stringr::str_split_fixed`.